# Diving into d3js.org, having challenge with setting colors for shapes

Tags: d3.js

I'm building 3 shapes (with the most awesome d3js.org library) from an array, different colors are specified, yet all shapes end up being black (#000000), not sure what's going on, just not picking up any color.

console.log always returns #00000. Shapes are drawn correctly. Code here, thanks

```
var data = [{"x":39.88,"y":15.38,"size":50.13,"color":"#048718","label":["label1"]},{"x":3.83,"y":9.67,"size":75.71,"color":"#ca5d2f","label":["label2"]},{"x":8.62,"y":19.21,"size":37.09,"color":"#bf69ab","label":["label3"]}];  

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
        .x(function (d){ return x(d.x); })
        .y(function (d){ return y(d.y); })
        .clipExtent([ [ 0, 0 ], [+width, +height] ]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1100)
        .attr("height", 380);

    var g = d3.select("svg").append("g")
        .attr("width", 1100)
        .attr("height", 380);

    var path = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(voronoi(data), polygon)
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("stroke","#FFFFFF")

        // >>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS LINE ----------------------------------

        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            return d3.rgb(d.color); 
        })
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "q" + (i) + ""; })
        //.attr("transform", function (d){ return "scale(" + (d.size*.01) + ")"; })
        //.attr("transform", function (d){ return "translate(" + (x(d.size)) + (y(d.size/3)) + ")"; })
        .attr("d", polygon);
```

[image]

Comment: No need for `d3.rgb(d.color)`. Just use `d.color` directly since it's already in hex format.

Comment: does @adilapapaya point solve your problem ?

Comment: No. Still returns a black box.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
return d3.rgb(d.point.color);   does the trick.